# Python wrapper over Powershell remoting

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-remoting

Is there some *python* wrapper over windows powershell remoting? I need to execute commands like moving, copying, zipping etc. on remote windows host.

quick googling resulted in this link https://gist.github.com/2850866
(just a little sample). I'm looking for a more complete library/etc.

Comment: IronPython has a [sample](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/downloads/get/2263) using PowerShell. Not sure if this qualifies your _python_ requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind using ssh on your windows machine, you should use [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/)

This is [Example Fabric usage with powershell](https://gist.github.com/2850866)

Comment: _Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool **for streamlining the use of SSH** for application deployment or systems administration tasks_ but I need the powershell remoting wrapper